# How to enable cross origin requests in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

I am trying to create a web application which works with cross-origin requests (CORS) in MVC 5. I have tried everything without any result.

Comment: Show us things you have tried, and their results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // New code
    config.EnableCors();
}


[EnableCors(origins: "http://systematixindia.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
   // Controller..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(i)using JSONP

to install this package, you can execute the following command from the NuGet package manager console.

--Install-Package WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp

after adding jsonp package, we need to add the following code-snippet in the App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs file. it creates an instance of JsonpMediaTypeFormatter class and adds to the config formatters object.

var jsonpFormatter = new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);                          config.Formatters.Add(jsonpFormatter);

after adding configuration change ajax request datatype: jsonp

(ii)using CORS

--Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

support for CORS can be enabled at three levels. these include the following:

Global level:

EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");

config.EnableCors(cors);

Controller level:

[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]

Action level:

you might need to disable CORS for a specific action or a group of actions

[DisableCors()]

or :

-add this code web.config in <system.webServer> tage

```
 <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods"
       value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
   </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```